Transform PPTX file to HTML using Tailwind CSS for design
I have a powerpoint file and i need to convert each slide into HTML and need to use tailwind CSS for the design part.
I tried converting using npm module pptx but did not work. I tried following code -
const pptx = require('pptx');
const fs = require('fs');

// Path to your PPT file
const pptPath = 'path/to/your/file.pptx';

// Create a new presentation object
const pres = new pptx.Presentation(fs.readFileSync(pptPath));

// Output directory for HTML files
const outputDir = 'path/to/output/directory';

// Convert each slide to HTML
pres.slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    const slideHtml = slide.getContent();
    
    // Add Tailwind CSS to the HTML
    const htmlContent = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Slide ${index + 1}</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            ${slideHtml}
        </body>
        </html>
    `;

// Write the HTML content to a file
    fs.writeFileSync(`${outputDir}/slide${index + 1}.html`, htmlContent);
});


I got the following error -


Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rjuna\.vscode\pptx to html\node_modules\pptx\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has 


a valid "main" entry...................................


code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',


  path: 'C:\\Users\\rjuna\\.vscode\\pptx to html\\node_modules\\pptx\\package.json',


  requestPath: 'pptx'```

